# How can I query across the same M2M field in multiple instances of the same model?

Tags: django-models

I have the following models:

```
class VocabEntry(OwnerModelMixin, ModelBase):
  prompt_text = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  response_text = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=vocab_upload_path, default=None)
  is_public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  last_used = models.DateField()


class Vocab(OwnerModelMixin, ModelBase):
  library = GenericRelation(Library)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

  entries = models.ManyToManyField(VocabEntry, related_name='vocabs')
```

I am trying to choose the n oldest VocabEntry.

I'm good with just one Vocab model, but I want to combine the results from multiple Vocab models and draw the n oldest VocabEntry from the combined results.

Is there a way to combine the results this way?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you aim to achieve. Why do you need the `Vocab` model for the oldest `VocabEntry`s?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I was just giving context when I mentioned what my ultimate goal was. The main issue is I am trying to combine a query of the 'entries' field of multiple Vocab objects, creating one single result.